# SQL Stored Procedure - issue using double replace

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use the replace function in order to replace some characters with some others :

```
if(@remarkspx like '%*0702*%') 
    begin
        replace(replace(@RemarksPX, '@', '.'), '#', '@')
        --print 'hello'
    end
```

When I'm running this "double replace" in a select query, it is perfectly working without any issue. However, here in this if block, I'm getting an error saying **Incorrect syntax near 'replace'**. If I'm using the print, everything works fine.

Any idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

sql function is not works individually either you have to select

```
select replace(replace('!@#$%^&*()', '@', '.'), '#', '@')
```

or set

```
set @var =  replace(replace('!@#$%^&*()', '@', '.'), '#', '@')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution !

Comment: @Traffy glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to set the output of the replace to a variable.

```
if(@remarkspx like '%*0702*%') 
    begin
        set @RemarksPX = replace(replace(@RemarksPX, '@', '.'), '#', '@')
        --print 'hello'
    end
```